# Horizontal and vertical autoscaling with AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate, aws-cdk

I have a little specific use-case here. I need to auto-scale a distributed web app running on ECS Fargate. The catch is that all the nodes need to keep the same data in memory (so increasing number of nodes does not help with memory pressure). Thus the increasing load can only be properly handled if it scales both horizontally (adding nodes) and vertically (increasing nodes memory).

Horizontal auto-scaling is simple. AWS CDK provides nice high-level constructs for load-balanced Fargate tasks and makes it super easy to add more tasks to handle CPU load:

```py
service = aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
    self,
    'FargateService',
    cpu=256,
    memory_limit_mib=512,
    ...
)

scalable_target = service.service.auto_scale_task_count(max_capacity=5)
scalable_target.scale_on_cpu_utilization('CpuScaling', target_utilization_percent=60)
```

What I'm looking for is the **vertical scaling** part. So far my best idea is the following:

1. Create a CloudWatch alarm for memory usage of the cluster. Trigger over 60%.
2. The alarm sends a message to an SNS topic, which triggers a lambda function.
3. The lambda describes the current task definition and parses out CPU and memory parameters. Then it creates a new version of the task definition with increased memory (and CPU if needed, because CPU and memory are not independent values in Fargate).
4. Finally the lambda updates the service with the new task definition. This should trigger a rolling update and result in a cluster with the same number of nodes, but each with bigger memory.

Do you think this could work? Is there any better solution? Any potential issues you can spot?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you try your idea? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, we use exactly this approach in production and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a reasonable way to go about this and could work.

An issue might be, that you don't keep track to the increased Memory demand in your IaC Template. This could result in the service being "reset" to minimal memory when you run a stack update that changes anything in the service.

To address this, you could create [SSM-Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) that hold the value of the CPU and Memory Units, which you [reference in your template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm). Your Lambda would need to update them with the new values as well. This way updates to the service via CloudFormation/CDK shouldn't trigger the scale-up process immediately.

You're only scaling up in terms of memory, is there a scenario in which the memory demand decreases and you can scale down as well? (This can be done via the same/or a similar mechanism, just something to keep in mind)

Comment: That's a very good point! Parameter store looks like the best option here.
I only mentioned scale up for simplicity. Scaling down can be achieved by the same mechanism. It can even be a single SNS topic and Lambda. Since the memory value will be sent in the message, the lambda can react accordingly (either scale up or down).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirement, vertical autoscaling of tasks in AWS Fargate. I have implemented below approach.

1. Cloudwatch Alarm triggers when cpu or memory of a service reaches a defined threshold
2. SNS topic will trigger a Lambda function
3. Lambda function will create a new task definition with increased resources and will update the running service
4. Lambda function will also send a slack notification with old and new resources

In this approach I'm using boto3 to provision ECS resources. Below is the Lambda function

```
#This lambda function only increments resources till 1VCPU, 2GB memory and only works single container
#Alarm, task and service naming should have the same dashes as we will be parsing that information
#cpu alarmname = env-project-appname-appsubname-cpu-ecs-alarm
#memory alarmname = env-project-appname-appsubname-memory-ecs-alarm
#taskdefinition name = env-project-appname-appsubname
#servicename = env-project-appname-appsubname
#make sure to give lambda required ecs permissions
#remove any ecs attributes which are not being used in your task defintion, example if you are not using tags remove tags in the functions 

import json
import boto3
import logging
import http.client

client = boto3.client('ecs')
LOG_EVENTS = True
LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"
SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = "Enter your slack webhook"
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)

def  list_tags_for_resource(resourceArn):
    tags = client.list_tags_for_resource(
    resourceArn=resourceArn
    )
    return tags

def describetaskdefinition(describetask_definition):
    get_taskdefinition_description = client.describe_task_definition(
            taskDefinition=describetask_definition
            )
    return get_taskdefinition_description

def singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,td_cpu,td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,
cd_name,cd_image,cd_cpu,cd_memory, cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags):
    new_task_defination = client.register_task_definition(
                            family=service_name,
                            requiresCompatibilities=td_requiresCompatibilities,
                            networkMode=td_networkMode,
                            taskRoleArn=td_taskRoleArn,
                            executionRoleArn=td_executionRoleArn,
                            cpu                      = td_cpu,
                            memory                   = td_memory,
                            runtimePlatform= td_runtimePlatform,
                            containerDefinitions=[
                                {
                                    "name"      : cd_name,
                                    "image"     : cd_image,
                                    "cpu":  cd_cpu,
                                    "memory": cd_memory,
                                    "essential" : cd_essential,
                                    "environment" : cd_environment,
                                    "secrets" : cd_secrets,
                                    "portMappings": cd_portMappings,
                                    "logConfiguration": cd_logConfiguration
                                }
                            ],
                            tags= td_tags
                        )
    return new_task_defination

def describeServices(cluster_name, serviceARNs):
    #serviceARNs from def list_specific_services 
    describe_services = client.describe_services(
            cluster=cluster_name,
            services=[serviceARNs]
        )
    return describe_services

def updateService(cluster_name,service_name,desiredCount,taskDefinationARN,deploymentConfiguration,networkConfiguration):
    client.update_service(
    cluster=cluster_name,
    service=service_name,
    desiredCount=desiredCount,
    taskDefinition=taskDefinationARN,
    deploymentConfiguration=deploymentConfiguration,
    networkConfiguration=networkConfiguration
)

def post_slack_message(hook_url, message):
    log.debug(f'Sending message: {json.dumps(message, indent=4)}')
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection('hooks.slack.com')
    connection.request('POST',
                       hook_url.replace('https://hooks.slack.com', ''),
                       json.dumps(message),
                       headers)
    response = connection.getresponse()
    log.debug('Response: {}, message: {}'.format(response.status, response.read().decode()))
    return response.status

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if LOG_EVENTS:
        log.info('Event logging enabled: `{}`'.format(json.dumps(event)))

    for record in event["Records"]:
        sns = record["Sns"]
        subject = sns["Subject"]
        cluster_name=subject.split('"')[1::2][0].rsplit('-',5)[0]+'-cluster'
        service_name=subject.split('"')[1::2][0].rsplit('-',3)[0]
        alarm_state= subject.split(':')[0]
        td_cpu= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['cpu']
        td_memory= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['memory']
        td_requiresCompatibilities =describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['requiresCompatibilities']
        td_networkMode =describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['networkMode']
        td_taskRoleArn = describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['taskRoleArn']
        td_executionRoleArn =describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['executionRoleArn']
        td_runtimePlatform = describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['runtimePlatform']
        td_taskDefinitionArn = describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
        td_tags = list_tags_for_resource(td_taskDefinitionArn)['tags']

        cd_name = describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['name']
        cd_image= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['image']
        cd_cpu= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['cpu']
        cd_memory= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['memory']
        cd_essential= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['essential']
        cd_environment= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['environment']
        cd_secrets= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['secrets']
        cd_portMappings= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['portMappings']
        cd_logConfiguration= describetaskdefinition(service_name)['taskDefinition']['containerDefinitions'][0]['logConfiguration']
        
        cs_desiredCount = describeServices(cluster_name, service_name)['services'][0]['desiredCount'] 
        cs_deploymentConfiguration = describeServices(cluster_name, service_name)['services'][0]['deploymentConfiguration']
        cs_networkConfiguration= describeServices(cluster_name, service_name)['services'][0]['networkConfiguration']
        if '-cpu-ecs-alarm' in subject and alarm_state in 'ALARM':
            if td_cpu == '1024':
                blocks = list()
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :red_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                                "*Lambda function triggered to scale cpu but maximum resource of [1024,2048]  is already allocated*"
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})

            elif td_cpu == '256' and td_memory in ('1024', '2048'):
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = '512'
                new_td_memory = td_memory
                new_cd_cpu= 512
                new_cd_memory = int(td_memory)
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory) 
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})            
            elif td_cpu == '256' and td_memory =='512':
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = '512'
                new_td_memory = '1024'
                new_cd_cpu= 512
                new_cd_memory = 1024
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory)   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response}) 
            elif td_cpu == '512' and td_memory in ('512','1024','2048'):
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = '1024'
                new_td_memory = '2048'
                new_cd_cpu= 1024
                new_cd_memory = 2048
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory)   
                                

                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response}) 
            else:
                message = "*Scaling Alert*"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                                "*Lambda function triggered but no cpu scaling configuration matched*"   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response}) 
        if '-memory-ecs-alarm' in subject and alarm_state in 'ALARM':
            if td_memory == '2048':
                blocks = list()
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :red_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                                "*Lambda function triggered to scale memory but maximum resource of [1024,2048]  is already allocated*"   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})

            elif td_memory == '512' and td_cpu in ('256','512'):
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = td_cpu
                new_td_memory = '1024'
                new_cd_cpu= int(td_cpu)
                new_cd_memory = 1024
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory)   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})
            elif td_memory == '512' and td_cpu =='1024':
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = td_cpu 
                new_td_memory = '2048'
                new_cd_cpu= int(td_cpu)
                new_cd_memory = '2048'
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory)   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})
            elif td_memory == '1024':
                blocks = list()
                new_td_cpu = td_cpu
                new_td_memory = '2048'
                new_cd_cpu= int(td_cpu)
                new_cd_memory = 2048
                new_task_defination=singleregisterTaskDefination(service_name,td_requiresCompatibilities,td_networkMode,td_taskRoleArn,td_executionRoleArn,new_td_cpu,new_td_memory,td_runtimePlatform,cd_name,cd_image,new_cd_cpu,new_cd_memory,cd_essential,cd_environment,cd_secrets,cd_portMappings,cd_logConfiguration,td_tags)
                cs_taskDefinition =new_task_defination['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
                updateService(cluster_name,service_name,cs_desiredCount,cs_taskDefinition,cs_deploymentConfiguration,cs_networkConfiguration)
                message = "*Scaling Alert* :large_green_circle:"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                               "*Current Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(td_cpu,td_memory) +'\n' +\
                               "*New Resources:* ['{}' , '{}']".format(new_td_cpu,new_td_memory)   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})
            else:
                blocks = list()
                message = "*Scaling Alert*"+'\n'+ "*Service Name:* "+service_name+'\n' + \
                                "*Lambda function triggered but no memory scaling configuration matched*"   
                blocks.append(
                        {
                            'type': 'section',
                            'text': {
                                'type': 'mrkdwn',
                                'text': message
                            }
                        }
                    )
                slack_message={'blocks': blocks}
                response = post_slack_message(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, slack_message)
                if response != 200:
                    log.error(
                        "Error: please troubleshoot '{}','{}'".format(cluster_name,service_name))
                    return json.dumps({"code": response})

    return json.dumps({"code": response})
```

Test Alarm event

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:ca-central-1:accountid:env-project-alarms-lambda-sns:fc8c2cef",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "f7574f1e-ddc1-5b7d-9dc7-14a91bb3e109",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ca-central-1:accountid:env-project-alarms-lambda-sns",
        "Subject": "ALARM: \"env-project-appname-appsubname-cpu-ecs-alarm\" in Canada (Central)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Some changes can be made to support more amount of resources, multi container and similar lambda function can be used to decrease the amount of resources as well.

Let me know how you have implemented your lambda function or what approach you have taken if you have a similar requirement.
Thank you!