# Auto-Scaling the CPU and Memory Usage of a Fargate-Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

Is there any way to prevent a failure of container run because of the lack of allocated resources in AWS Fargate? Is there any way to auto-scale the container if the allocated memory not enough? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. What you are asking about is called vertical scaling. The only service in AWS currently that can automatically scale vertically like that is Aurora Serverless. Most services in AWS only offer horizontal scaling.

Fargate requires you to specify CPU and Memory settings at the time of deployment and the individual containers will never be assigned more resources than that, until you change the setting and redeploy.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your quick response! Is there a workaround? A Lambda function or so? Like automatic monitoring and adjustment of a config json in a programmatic way...

Comment: I have found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628660/horizontal-and-vertical-autoscaling-with-aws-ecs-fargate

Comment: There is no way to adjust the memory and CPU of a currently running task. Any adjustments require destroying and recreating the task. There is no way to keep your process running. Your question is about "preventing a failure of container run".

Answer (score 0):

Nope. As Mark B mentioned, this is vertical scaling and is not inline with cloud best practices.

If you are getting any errors relating to the container resources, you should adjust the container definitions to allocate the required CPU and Memory capacities.