# AWS ECS service vertical scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

This is somewhat follow-up / clarification question of this:

[Horizontal and vertical autoscaling with AWS ECS Fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628660/horizontal-and-vertical-autoscaling-with-aws-ecs-fargate)

I'm in the same situations, as the OP, and assuming that I'm going with the second answer (Cloudwatch + SNS + Lambda), I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible, to scale down the up-scaled service, if the memory consumption doesn't needed? How?
2. Our application caches data, that as "last resort" is written back to database: Is it possible to configure AWS ECS to NOT!!! start a new service than shut down the old one, but FIRST shut down the old service and when it is done, start a new one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible, to scale down the up-scaled service, if the memory consumption doesn't needed? How?

Yes, you would just need a second CloudWatch alarm to trigger when the memory consumption is below a certain threshold, just like you had for when it was above a certain threshold.

> 2. Our application caches data, that as "last resort" is written back to
>    database: Is it possible to configure AWS ECS to NOT!!! start a new
>    service than shut down the old one, but FIRST shut down the old
>    service and when it is done, start a new one?

It sounds like you only ever want at most one instance of the service running at a time. And you need to make sure the previous instance has shut down, before creating the new instance.

You would need to set the ECS Service's `desiredCount` to `1`, and the service's Deployment Configuration settings as follows:

```
maximumPercent: 100
minimumHealthyPercent: 0
```

With a desired count of `1`, maximum percent of `100` and minimum healthy percent of `0`, whenever you update the service's task definition and trigger a new deployment, ECS will first shutdown the existing ECS task (because you have told it you want at most 1 running at a time) and only then will it start the updated ECS task.