# Decrease AWS ECS Service startup time

Tags: amazon-ecs

This is somewhat follow-up / strongly related question of this post:
[AWS ECS service vertical scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300551/aws-ecs-service-vertical-scaling/76301639#76301639)

So given the following ECS Cluster setup with the related EC2 and ASC settings:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "startup" {
  name                   = "startup"
  update_default_version = true
  image_id               = "ami-05339d597592d45cf" # Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) x86_64 AMI
  instance_type          = "t2.large"
  user_data = base64encode(<<-EOT
    #!/bin/bash
    echo ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
    ${join("\n", [for ssh_key in var.ssh_keys : "echo \"${ssh_key}\" >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"])}
    chown ec2-user: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 0600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
  EOT
  )

  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_agent.name
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "startup" {
  name                = "startup"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [var.subnet_id]

  desired_capacity          = 0
  min_size                  = 0
  max_size                  = 10
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.startup.id
  }

  warm_pool {
    max_group_prepared_capacity = -1
    min_size                    = 1
    pool_state                  = "Stopped"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "startup" {
  name = "startup"
  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.startup.arn

    managed_scaling {
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "providers" {
  cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
  capacity_providers =     [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.startup.name]
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = var.module_name
}
```

The problem is if I start a service using an autoscaling group, that doesn't manage service right now (scaling vertically), the startup takes around **4-7min**

This is unacceptable from the business point of view.

As I heave learned, the most time consuming task is to pull the docker image, so the questions:

1. How can I "pre-fetch" the docker image into the EC2 instances in the warm pool / pre-fetch into the aws_launch_template, so when the ECS service starts, don't spend time to pull it
2. **ANY** other suggestion to boost up ECS Service startup would be welcomed (the acceptable goal would be in the **sec range**)

Comment: Why is that "unacceptable"? Don't you have instances already running that can handle the load? Otherwise maybe adjust your metrics so that your scaling happens earlier!?

Comment: There can be plenty of pitfalls when it comes to the ECS Service startup time - large Docker image that needs to be pulled, ECS Task health check configuration, your code that does a lot during the startup, etc. If you need something that is available within a second I would rather look into Lambda functions. Although even with Lambdas, if you use some JVM-based languages like Java it may take longer than a second, if it is ahead of time compiled language like Go or C# starting from .NET 7 the startup time will be within 100ms-1s

Comment: @luk2302 It is vertical scaling, so I need to start a completely new service (as I have understand, no way to modify running service by modifying the underlying EC2)

Comment: @OlegI That's why I tried to pull docker image when the warm pool has been created, so my intention was that the ECS / docker agent who will manage my ECS Service on a particular EC2 instance, will see that the requested agent is there, so I can save that time.
Lambda is not an option due to the 15min timout